# Numpy allclose tolerances for single and half precision?

Tags: python, numpy, precision

`atol=1e-8` isn't suitable for single or half precision, unsure of `rtol=1e-5` - they appear calibrated for `float64`.

What should be the standard for `float32` and `float16`?

A reference is preferred - I found [this](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/) but there's no summary and I don't know how applicable it is to `np.allclose`. Simply reasoning also works.

Comment: `mpmath.almosteq` may give you ideas

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable. There have been contexts where I cared about matching the output of an existing method to within 1 ULP, and contexts where I was happy to have something within 0.1% of the correct answer. Is 0.1% "close?" Depends on the application.

Comment: there's a long time open issue re `isclose`, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161.  https://peps.python.org/pep-0485/#numpy-isclose is PEP re adding `isclose` to `math`.

Comment: @hpaulj That's great, thanks - linking informative [math.isclose creator comment](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161#issuecomment-350021545) here

Comment: Tolerances can also differ based on the calculations.  Some long sums are notorious for bad errors.  Similarly for inversion and matrix multiplication with nearly singular matrices.

Comment: @hpaulj Of course. That's why I ask about "standards", i.e. general best defaults. The three libs have ones for `float64`, I but seek its 32 & 16 equivalents. In fact your linked thread appears to include discussing exactly this ([e.g.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10161#issuecomment-852783433)) - I've not read everything yet.

Comment: @hpaulj [May interest](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/43111/38029) you